# IIS URLRewrite forward to different port

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting

I would like to host multiple APIs in IIS which should all be accessible via the standard http port 80. Internally IIS should then forward this request to some other local port e.g.:

http://someip:80/api1/request1 -> http://localhost:1234/request1

http://someip:80/api2/request2 -> http://localhost:5678/request2

Im trying to achieve this by using URLRewrite with the following rule

[image]

As far as I understand what I've set up should

a) match any request

b) check if the QUERY_STRING matches /bosswrapper/(.*) and place the (.*) content in {C:1}

c) replace that request with http://localhost:12345/{C:1}

so that means http://somehost/bosswrapper/foo/bar should become http://localhost:12345/foo/bar.

When I call http://localhost:12345/foo/bar directly everything works, when I call http://somehost/bosswrapper/foo/bar it does not. What am I missing?

Comment: Mistake 3, https://halfblood.pro/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Comment: @LexLi ARR is in fact installed and proxy enabled. I will however try to enable Failed Request Tracing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://somehost/bosswrapper/foo/bar -> http://localhost:12345/foo/bar

Your rewrite rule is not exactly correct, try the following rewrite rule in `web.cofig`:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="my rule">
                <match url="bosswrapper/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:12345/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

[image]

The `QUERY_STRING` server variable match the parameter string of the URL, should not be used to match the path part of the URL.

Also your rewrite rule should be created on the site where the hostname is `somehost`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that! Thanks to your comment I've also discovered that of course the QUERY_STRING is wrong and should be replaced with PATH_INFO instead! This works now. Is there any advantage in using your pattern vs my condition?

Comment: The difference is that if the AllowPathInfoForScriptMappings metabase property is set to true, `PATH_INFO` will only contain "/zip" (for example, full path information is `"/vdir/myisapi.dll/zip"`. ) and ISAPI applications such as ASP will break. Of course, I think both ways are ok.